# TypeError: (0 , tslib__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__.__extends) is not a function

Tags: javascript, angular, webpack, charts

I try to install a chart library with Angular 14. I tried ngx-charts and ngx-echarts. For both I get the following exception when I open the page which contains the chart in the browser:

> Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: (0 ,
> tslib__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__.**extends) is not a function
> TypeError: (0 , tslib__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1**.__extends) is not a
> function
> at Handler.js:32:14
> at 328 (Handler.js:31:19)
> at **webpack_require** (bootstrap:19:1)
> at 14215 (transformPath.js:81:2)
> at **webpack_require** (bootstrap:19:1)
> at 64749 (Scheduler.js:557:1)
> at **webpack_require** (bootstrap:19:1)
> at 52437 (core.js:51:1)
> at **webpack_require** (bootstrap:19:1)
> at 72750 (node_modules_echarts_index_js.js:70:75)
> at resolvePromise (zone.js:1211:31)
> at zone.js:1118:17
> at zone.js:1134:33
> at asyncGeneratorStep (asyncToGenerator.js:6:1)
> at _throw (asyncToGenerator.js:29:1)
> at _ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:372:26)
> at Object.onInvoke (core.mjs:26318:33)
> at _ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:371:52)
> at Zone.run (zone.js:134:43)
> at zone.js:1275:36

My module looks like this:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    SiteTemplateComponent,
    DisclaimerComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule,
    SharedModule,
    NgxEchartsModule.forRoot({
      /**
       * This will import all modules from echarts.
       * If you only need custom modules,
       * please refer to [Custom Build] section.
       */
      echarts: () => import('echarts'), // or import('./path-to-my-custom-echarts')
    }),
  ],
  exports: [CommonModule,
    HomeRoutingModule,
    SiteTemplateComponent]
})
export class HomeModule { }
```

My component.html like this:

```
<div echarts [options]="chartOption" class="demo-chart"></div>
```

Is saw that they use Angular 14 in the github project (https://github.com/xieziyu/ngx-echarts/blob/master/package.json) as well. I'm also using the same packages in my project. Any idea why this error occurs for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found the issue.

In tsconfig.json I have added the following line, since Visual Studio was not showing intellisense for typescript correctly:

```
{
...
    "paths": {
      "tslib": [ "./node_modules/tslib/tslib.d.ts" ]
    }
  },
```

After removing the tslib path the error seems to be gone.